# PHP - Comparando informações

Tags: php, if

Estou tentando comparar o número inserido no textbox com um número definido na variável, deste jeito:

```
<?php
 $campo1 = $_POST['um'];
 $valor1 = 1;

   if($campo1 == $valor1){
      $msg="ok";
   }
   else{
      $msg="erro";
   }

?>
```

Textbox:

```
<div class="6u"><input type="text" name="um" class="text" placeholder="Primeiro número" /></div>
```

Mas sempre retorna false, alguma idéia?

Comment: As duas variáveis são do mesmo DataType?

Comment: Acredito que sim. Estou comparando somente números inteiros.

Comment: verificou o ponto e virgula na linha 2?

Comment: Em `$campo1 = $_POST['um']` falta um `;` no final.

Comment: Só esqueci de colocar, mas no código original está com `;`

Comment: O problema não parece ser o código mas os valores ... `var_dump()` na dúvida!

Comment: No seu código original a condição não estaria com `===` ? Porque no caso o `1` do `$campo1` é `string` e o de `$valor1` é inteiro... aqui pra mim seu código funciona como está, acho que porque está com `==`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui pra mim deu certo, mexi no código:

```
<?php
    $campo1 = $_POST['um'];
    $valor1 = 1;
    $msg = "erro";

    if(( int ) $campo1 == $valor1){
       $msg = "ok";
    }

    echo $msg;
?>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é com o código original, que com certeza não é igual ao da pergunta, já que o código da pergunta **funciona perfeitamente do jeito que está**.

Provavelmente deve estar com `===` na condição (mas claro que pode ser outra coisa errada no código original).

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/jOIUhm) um exemplo com o código da pergunta (pegando o valor que seria obtido por `post`) com a string `"1"` na variável `$campo1`.

No entanto, se você mudar a condição para `===` já vai dar erro, veja [aqui no Ideone](https://ideone.com/uB65lC).

Como o @rray sugeriu no comentário, veja o `var_dump` das variáveis (neste caso enviadas por `post` através de um `input` do `type="text"`, da exata forma como está no código da pergunta):

```
string '1' (length=1)
int 1
```

Isso acontece porque o campo  `input` do `type="text"` envia sempre uma string (mesmo que seja um número), enquanto a declaração da variável  `$valor1` está como um inteiro, e o comparador `===` requer que os valores sejam **idênticos**, inclusive o tipo.

Do [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
$a === $b   // Idêntico Verdadeiro (TRUE) se $a é igual a $b, e eles são do mesmo tipo.
```

Detalhe: A resposta aceita funcionaria inclusive com o comparador `===`, porque transformou a string em inteiro com `(int)`, o que é desnecessário no caso, por estar usando `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Se for para comparar string, use strcmp:

`echo strcmp($campo1, $campo1);`